# cannot resolve method setAllowNewEmailsAccounts

Tags: java, android

Am getting an error "error: **cannot find symbol method setAllowNewEmailsAccounts(boolean)**" this is the piece of my code that might help figure out the solution. is the method outdated and if yes, how can I implement the new method?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnLogin;
private final static int LOGIN_PERMISSION=1000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAllowNewEmailsAccounts(true).build(),LOGIN_PERMISSION
            );

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using outdated code for Firebase AuthUI:

Here is how you make Email sign In with **AllowNewEmailAccounts** :

replace the code inside your **onClick()** function with this.

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Collections.singletonList(
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setAllowNewAccounts(true).build());

startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setLogo(your app logo)
                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                .build(),
                        LOGIN_PERMISSION);
```

Google made some changes in latest version of Firebase Auth Ui library.